# Moving files between different WSL2 instances?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

If it is possible, how can I move files from one WSL instance to another directly? This would be useful when trying out new distributions, e.g. for copying /home from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

I am weary of doing this through explorer by accessing [`\\wsl$` in the windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185560/where-are-the-files-inside-wsl2-physically-stored), it doesn't seem to reliably transfer all the files and feels wrong overall.

Comment: It seems there is a way: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4574

Comment: Ok, the proper way seems to be this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#mount-a-vhd-in-wsl

Comment: The last one is (currently) only available if you are running Windows Insider Preview (beta).  The `mount --bind` idea in the first comment you posted isn't too bad a workaround in the meantime.  I think it's overly complicated by the poster's attempt to automatically set it up each time.  If you just want to copy/move between instances, doing a `bind --mount` on one of them to `/mnt/wsl` is probably sufficient.  But who am I to judge for being "overly complicated" - I use Ansible to set up my new WSL instances ;-).

Comment: I've adapted a method from the Github issue referenced in the first comment, along with a few other methods, in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1659355/1210833) where it's on-topic ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## How to share data between different WSL instances

### 1. Create shared directory which is not included in any WSL instances

```
mkdir /mnt/wsl/share
```

This will create `/mnt/wsl/share` directory shared across all WSL instances. You can share data via this shared directory.

**WARNING: the shared directory's filesystem lives in memory and thus a `wsl.exe --shutdown` would wipe them from existence.**

However, it is still impossible to directly copy/paste data between WSL instances.

### 2. Create shared directory included in a WSL instance

You can make existing directory in WSL instance shared across other WSL instances by using bind mount.

For example, you have two WSL instances, *Ubuntu-A* and *Ubuntu-B*.

**1. Open `~/.profile` in *Ubuntu-A* and add below code.**

```
# bind mount shared directory
if [ ! -d /mnt/wsl/share-a ]; then
  mkdir /mnt/wsl/share-a
  wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-A -u root mount --bind / /mnt/wsl/share-a/
fi
```

**2. Open `~/.profile` in *Ubuntu-B* and add below code.**

```
# bind mount shared directory
if [ ! -d /mnt/wsl/share-b ]; then
  mkdir /mnt/wsl/share-b
  wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-B -u root mount --bind / /mnt/wsl/share-b/
fi
```

This will automatically mount the root directory (`/`) of *Ubuntu-A* to `/mnt/wsl/shared-a/` and do the same thing for *Ubuntu-B* when you launch WSL.

Comment: On item 2, I put the following in my ~/.profile

```
if [[ -n "${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}" ]]; then
   if [[ -d "/mnt/wsl/"${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}" ]]; then
      ls "/mnt/wsl/${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}"

Comment: is there any way to keep them from being wiped out of existence?

Comment: Has the `--bind` option gone away? Replaced with...? `wsl.exe -d AlmaLinux9 -u root --bind /foo /bar` results in the error `Invalid command line argument: --bind`.

Answer (score 5):

On item 2, I put the following in my ~/.profile (well technically my .bash_profile).

```
if [[ -n "${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}" ]]; then
   if [[ -d "/mnt/wsl/${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}" ]]; then
      ls "/mnt/wsl/${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}"
   else 
      mkdir "/mnt/wsl/${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}"
      # note the terminating / on the directory name below!
      wsl.exe -d ${WSL_DISTRO_NAME} -u root mount --bind / "/mnt/wsl/${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}/"
   fi
fi
```

The result is every distro I start gets its root directory mounted with the "obvious" name.

Comment: I find it cleaner to do the same thing through `/etc/fstab` as documented in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1659355/1210833).  One line in `/etc/fstab` handles all of that logic.